# Java API URL pattern for multiple path placeholders

Tags: java, rest, url-parameters

I want to pass two placeholder values to the API, for example details on location id : 50 of the organization is 5

api.xxx.com/organization/5/location/50

Below is my code and it gives a 404. But the code works if you make it for just organization.

How can I get it to work with both placeholders?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/organization/*/location/*")
public class LocationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        if (pathInfo.length == 4) {
            String organizationId = pathInfo[2];
            String locationId = pathInfo[4];
            // Implement your logic here to fetch data based on organizationId and locationId
            // You can return the results as JSON or any other format.
            // For example:
            // LocationInfo locationInfo = locationService.getLocationInfo(organizationId, locationId);
            // response.getWriter().write(locationInfo.toString());
            
            response.getWriter().write("Organization ID: " + organizationId + ", Location ID: " + locationId);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.getWriter().write("Invalid URL");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you're trying to access the path parameters. Arrays in Java are 0-indexed, so when you split the path, you should access the values using the correct indices.

I will change the following

1. pathInfo[2] to pathInfo[1] for organizationId. pathInfo[4] to
2. pathInfo[3] for locationId.

Can you please try this code with alterations done to address the issue?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/organization/*/location/*")
public class LocationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        if (pathInfo.length == 4) {
            String organizationId = pathInfo[1];
            String locationId = pathInfo[3];
            // Implement your logic here to fetch data based on organizationId and locationId
            // You can return the results as JSON or any other format.
            // For example:
            // LocationInfo locationInfo = locationService.getLocationInfo(organizationId, locationId);
            // response.getWriter().write(locationInfo.toString());
            
            response.getWriter().write("Organization ID: " + organizationId + ", Location ID: " + locationId);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.getWriter().write("Invalid URL");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Buddhika Ariyaratne, you need to fix the indexing value. In addition, noticed the url pattern for the servlet seems invalid.

Instead of `@WebServlet("/organization/*/location/*")`, it should be `@WebServlet("/organization/*")`